# How to confirm transaction from gnosis Safe account?

Tags: gnosis-safe

I create a Safe account from my EOA, and I try to create another Safe account from that created Safe account.

In this situation, how to confirm transaction?
There is no change in the transaction queue.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the image that you attached, you can see that your Safe is a 1/1. You can see this on the left side of the image, there's a small green circle at the top right of the favicon representing the Safe that has '1/1' in it. Let's explain what this means, and why it's relevant to your question.

You're clearly familiar with Safes being a multisig - there are signers who are members of the Safe, and a threshold of how many of them it takes for the Safe to send a transaction. These are sometimes referred to as *m of n* accounts, meaning that you need *m* accounts of the total of *n* signers for a transaction to happen. In Safe's UI, a proposed transaction that has not yet met a quorum of *m* signatures is placed in something called the Transaction Queue.

What's the m and n of your Safe? That's what the 1/1 represents. Your Safe only has one signer (you), meaning it has an *n* of 1. It should now be obvious that the *m* is also 1. This means that any transaction you propose in the Safe will be automatically executed, bypassing the queue since there's no reason for it to go there - all of the signers have already agreed to the transaction, since there's only one signer, and that signer is proposing it.

That's why you don't see anything in the queue - the 'Waiting for Transaction Confirmation' on the right of the image means that it's already been sent to the blockchain, and is waiting to be included in a block.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks very much!!!!!!